# Custom data source with Coded UI Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I've Googled this extensively and I'm not sure if this can be done. I want to implement my own data source. For example in the test the result would be:

```
[MyDataSource("xx", CustomEnum.Something), TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod()
{
    var fromSounce = TestContext.DataRow["key"].ToString();
    // Testing
}
```

The class DataSourceAttribute that DataSource inherits from is explicitly marked as non-inheritable. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any way to achive this goal?

Comment: @ArturShamsutdinov No, sorry. I ended up doing a combination of things. I have a master excel sheet that exports to individual .CSV files that the tests use as parameterization. I also have a set of DAOs where I can access more one dimensional data based on the test name, e.g. `TestData.GetDataSet(TestContext.TestName)`.

Comment: I need to do the same thing!  I can't figure out a way either...